# I can't find `Web Form Using Master Page` in Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am reading [Microsoft® ASP.NET 4 Step by Step](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780735627017.do) and I am on page 148.

The tutorial says to add a new `Web Form Using Master Page` item, but I can't find it!

The screenshot in the book is below:

[image: Book Screenshot]

This is what I am seeing:

[image: My Screenshot]

I doubt the book is wrong, so what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compare those screenshots very carefully, you will see that in the top one, the user has clicked on "Visual C#" in the left panel.

You have used a different approach to navigate to your choices. It appears that you have typed "master" in the search box in the upper right of the screen. On the left panel, "Search Results" is highlighted.

**I believe that if you click on "Visual C#" on the left, you will see what the screenshot from the book shows.**

What you have found in your search is the selection for creating a Master Page. What you are seeking is how to create a Web Form, and specifically a Web Form using a Master Page.

Answer (score 6):

A bit late in answering, but the screenshot posted by JMK from the book is likely showing the UI from Visual Web Developer. In Visual Studio, you would pick "Web Form". Then, on the bottom-right next to the Name field, there are two checkboxes (seen on JMK's second screenshot). Check off "Select master page". Click Add (or press Enter) and you will get to pick the master page you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for answering, the book turned out to be a bit rubbish anyway, I've read better books since and now know how to create a web form with a master page!

Answer (score 4):

Right click on your master page and select "add content page".

[image]

Answer (score 4):

the name of "Web form using master page" is **ContentPage** on visual studio 2012 (framwWork 4) just add a ContentPage from "add -->new item> contentPage"

Answer (score 0):

I found "Web Form using Master Page" is missing in scenario of website.
for website u can add "Web Form using Master Page" through right click on your Master page and select "add content page".
while when you make a project its show in add new items.